# Service can't be started: can't load assembly

Tags: windows, wcf, exception, windows-services, self-hosting

I'm trying to put together a Windows Service, which hosts a WCF service.
My project structure is as follows:

- Service
- Service.Contracts
- Service.Host
- Service.Setup

The Service.Host project contains the ProjectInstaller, the Service.Setup project the WindowsInstaller.

Now, everything builds and installs just fine, but when I try to start the service, it immediately stops running with the following message in my event log:

```
Service cannot be started. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Service' from 
assembly 'Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at Host.Service.OnStart(String[] args)
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

When I check the output folder of my setup project I can see both the Service.dll as well as the Service.Contracts.dll... This puts me off guard. How do I debug this when everything builds ok? What to do?

Comment: What is your Service assembly dependent on, reference wise? Is you service process running with enough privileges to load those references? And you mention that you've checked the output folder of the setup project, but are the assemblies actually installed?

Comment: Do you know how to use "Attach to process"?

Comment: @Maarten: The Service assembly is dependant on some .NET assemblies and Service.Contracts. How do I check that Maarten? All I know I see the service in my list of services, but can't start it, so I guess it's installed properly.

Comment: @Amiram, yes, but how is that helping in this case as there's no process to attach to.

Comment: Maybe the user that runs the service doesn't have permissions to the dll folder

Comment: It's running as a NetworkService, while I'm logged in with administrative rights.

Comment: @fuaaark - the required references you can see in visual studio. What version of .net are you using, and is that version installed on the system you're testing on? In case of .net 4.0, are you using .net framework 4.0 full profile, and does the testing system only have framework 4.0 client profile?

Comment: Sorry I meant to answer the question about it being installed -> How can I check that, as the service shows in services.msc, I assume it's been properly installed. No client profile, in any of the projects. Funny thing is, the bare minumum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx does work. So I'm comparing configurations at the moment to see what's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: stupid error with namespace declarations.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like this (where the failure is happening on start) it can be difficult to attach a debugger.  If I'm still in development I like to put in the extra statement `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`.  This will automatically [launch a debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) when the code runs.  I would suggest putting that line of code just below the `OnStart` to see if you can get more information out of the issue.

Comment: this made no difference for me...debugger did not launch.